# Cameras intelbrass com python

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

Gostaria de saber se é possível pegar imagens de uma camera intelbrass através do ip pelo python, pesquisei bastante e não achei nada, o código que chegou mais perto foi esse aqui:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.18.37:8090/video')
```

e apresentou esse erro:

```
Connection to tcp://192.168.18.37:8090 failed: Error number -138 occurred
```

Comment: Para acessar tem usuário e senha? Além disso, o protocolo para acessar é `rtsp`. Caso tenha usuário e senha, então seria assim: `cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://usuario:senha@192.168.18.37:8090/1')`.

Comment: ja testei desse jeito tambem, apresentou o mesmo erro

Comment: Você olhou o manual da câmera? você configurou para essa porta?

Comment: Sim, tenho um sistema que roda através dessa porta

Answer (score 2):

Olá, para esse modelo de câmera você pode usar a seguinte estrutura: **[http://usuário:senha@ip:porta/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=0&subtype=1](http://usu%C3%A1rio:senha@ip:porta/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=0&subtype=1)**

```
import cv2

camIp = 'http://admin:admin@10.0.0.100:8080/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi? 
channel=0&subtype=1'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camIp)

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Caso precise de mais informação leia este forum da própria empresa: http://forum.intelbras.com.br/viewtopic.php?t=55618

**IMPORTANTE:**
***Testem o link da câmera no VLC Player antes do código, para eliminar problemas!***

[>>Exemplo do VLC<<](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vTb6CP0N1M)

Comment: ja tentei dessa forma, nao retornou nada

Comment: Bom uso essa marca de câmeras a um tempo, e funciona para diferentes modelos e gerações.  Testa seus links antes no PROGRAMA VLC Player.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vTb6CP0N1M   se não conseguir abri-las em tempo real nesse software o problema é o link, mas se abrir o problema é teu código.